# Next.js TypeScript - The automatically generated tsconfig.json file is missing moduleResolution

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have an existing Next.js project and I was migrating it to typescript.
I install all typescript realted packages as follows:

```
npm install --save-dev typescript @types/react @types/node
```

The generated tsconfig.json gives an error like
`The automatically generated tsconfig.json file is missing moduleResolution`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Manual Setup:

- Add `"moduleResolution": "node"` in tsconfig.json

Else try [Automatic Setup](https://nextjs.org/docs#automatic-setup)